# Is it possible to select multiple objects with box selection?

Tags: qt3d

I know that with `QObjectPicker` I can mouse pick a single entity. But how can I select multiple objects by drawing a rectangle on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is actually pretty complicated. But here are my two cents:

---

**If you only need to be able to select unoccluded objects**

(i.e. don't need to select occluded ones) you could add a second frame graph branch to your existing one and draw each object with a unique color but to an offscreen texture. Then retrieve this texture, check which colors lie within the drawn rectangle and retrieve the corresponding objects and select them (compare to [this question/answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45445/what-method-replaces-gl-select-for-box-selection)).

I'm not sure how well this works in Qt3D because I've always had some issues with `QRenderCapture`. It didn't seem to have an impact where I added it in the frame graph, i.e. always captured the last state so maybe even if you have multiple render targets it might capture the wrong one etc. Qt3D is still in a pretty rough state I'd say.

If you need an example of how to render to an offscreen texture check out [my example on GitHub](https://github.com/florianblume/Qt3D-OffscreenRenderer).

---

**If you need to be able to select occluded objects too**

then it gets pretty complicated. I'm just providing some ideas here. I don't know if they will work.

If you don't have that many objects maybe you could implement the idea from above for each single object. I.e. for each object you have an offscreen frame graph branch that filters out all other objects. Then you could check each rendered texture for the rectangle drawn with the mouse. But again I'm not sure how well this works with Qt3D and if you have many objects (like in a game) it will probably crash because of the many offscreen textures.

You could also implement something like "inverse" frustum culling. In frustum culling, you omit rendering objects that lie outside the view frustum of the camera. You could compute a frustum using the rectangle coordinates drawn with the mouse. Check out the [`QFrustumCulling` code](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/dev/src/render/jobs/frustumcullingjob.cpp). You would need to compute the planes differently of course, using a modified view matrix. When the user draws the rectangle, compute the frustum and check all objects. Unfortunately, this also selects objects whose bounding sphere intersects with the frustum, even though you might visible not touch any part of the object. If that bothers you, you could directly select all objects whose sphere is completely within the frustum and for all objects which only partly intersect do the intersection computation on a per-triangle basis and exit computation for the current object as soon as a triangle intersects the frustum. Depending on the number of triangles this could be very costly computational-wise.

I'd definitely stick to being able to select only unoccluded objects especially because picking in OpenGL seems to be realized by drawing the ojbects with colors these days.